# Error: "DoesNotExist at / Menu matching query does not exist."

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I was practicing with wagtail, following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8a9ROUUJXU) when i got that *DoesNotExist at / Menu matching query does not exist*  error, but i can not find the root of the problem. I would really appreciate any help or knowlegde

[image: error-message]

Django: 3.2.9

Python: 3.10.0

debug_toolbar: 3.2.2

django_extensions: 3.1.5

taggit: 1.5.1

wagtail.core: 2.15.1

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/

Django Version: 3.2.9
Python Version: 3.10.0
Installed Applications:
['home',
 'search',
 'flex',
 'streams',
 'site_settings',
 'subscribers',
 'blog',
 'menus',
 'wagtail.contrib.forms',
 'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
 'wagtail.contrib.settings',
 'wagtail.contrib.routable_page',
 'wagtail.contrib.sitemaps',
 'wagtail.contrib.modeladmin',
 'wagtail.embeds',
 'wagtail.sites',
 'wagtail.users',
 'wagtail.snippets',
 'wagtail.documents',
 'wagtail.images',
 'wagtail.search',
 'wagtail.admin',
 'wagtail.core',
 'modelcluster',
 'taggit',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'django_extensions']
Installed Middleware:
['django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\pedro.garcia\website\mysite\mysite\templates\base.html, error at line 3
   Menu matching query does not exist.
   1 : {% load static wagtailuserbar menus_tags %}
   2 : 
   3 :  {% get_menu "main" as navigation %} 
   4 : 
   5 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   6 : <html class="no-js" lang="en">
   7 :     <head>
   8 :         <meta charset="utf-8" />
   9 :         <title>
   10 :             {% block title %}
   11 :                 {% if self.seo_title %}{{ self.seo_title }}{% else %}{{ self.title }}{% endif %}
   12 :             {% endblock %}
   13 :             {% block title_suffix %}


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 100, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 100, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py", line 192, in render
    output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\website\mysite\menus\templatetags\menus_tags.py", line 10, in get_menu
    return Menu.objects.get(slug=slug)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 435, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: Menu matching query does not exist.
```

mysite\menus\views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

mysite\menus\templatetags\menus_tags.py

```
from django import template

from ..models import Menu

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag()
def get_menu(slug):
    return Menu.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

Comment: Please see how to write a [mre]. Just giving an error likely won't get you great answers. The answer to your question simply is there is no `Menu` that matches the slug you have. You get that error on the line `return Menu.objects.get(slug=slug)` which is in the function `get_menu` which is written in the file `menus\templatetags\menus_tags.py`

Comment: Show your `views.py` file

Comment: There is no `Menu` object with slug="main".

Comment: @Rvector the views.py from the "menus" folder you mean?